# Unity How to Spawn Prefab at Random Decimal Position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a project that needs enemy prefabs that are on a wall. Each enemy is spawned at an random x and random y coordinate. I have figured out how to spawn them in an integer range, such as (0, 8) or (-3, 5). I did this using Random.Range. Random.Range only seems to take whole numbers, but not decimals. How would I spawn enemies between a decimal range, such as (-0.5, 3.2)?

This is what I have for spawning enemies so far:

```
xPos = Random.Range(-5, 6);
yPos = Random.Range(0, 6);
Instantiate(theEnemy, new Vector3(xPos, yPos, -2), Quaternion.identity);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Random.Range have an overload method which creates float numbers.

Such as

```
var randomFloat = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
```

You just need to give float numbers as parameter.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks so much! I didn't know it was that simple haha